# Displaying HTML Tables in SSRS 2008 R2

Tags: html, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, rdl

I used a text box to insert HTML-formatted text, and trying to insert **table** HTML tag into the placeholder.

According to this website,

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff519562(v=sql.105).aspx

**table** HTML tag is not supported and ignored during report processing.

Do you have any idea how I can display HTML table in SSRS? In the Textbox, only HTML-formatted text will be rendered...

```
<Textbox Name="tbContent">
    <Paragraphs>
        <Paragraph>
            <TextRuns>
                <TextRun>
                    <Value>=Fields!dataset.Value</Value>
                    <MarkupType>HTML</MarkupType>
                </TextRun>
            </TextRuns>
        </Paragraph>
    </Paragraphs>
</Textbox>
```

Answer (score 1):

Per the link you posted:

```
The following is a complete list of tags that will render as HTML when defined as placeholder text:
Hyperlinks: <A HREF>
Fonts: <FONT>
Header, style and block elements: <H{n}>, <DIV>, <SPAN>,<P>, <DIV>, <LI>, <HN>
Text format: <B>, <I>, <U>, <S>
List handling: <OL>, <UL>, <LI>
```

The SSRS table functionality in itself is pretty powerful and can be highly customized. Is there any reason you are requiring the use of an HTML table?

Comment: Thank you Cyberdrew. In a blank textbox, a user can type whatever they want. It could be just plain text, but a user can sometimes insert table with plain text. Any suggestion?